# Surjective map results in subrepresentation

Tags: representation-theory, modules

I need to prove that a surjective homomorphism of finite $\mathbb{F}_p[\Delta]$-modules 
$$A \twoheadrightarrow B$$
results in $B$ being a subrepresenation of $A$ of the group $\Delta$ of order prime to $p$. I, however, don't know if this really leads to a subrepresentation, since I've always thought, that a subrepresentation should look like $B \subset A$ in module language.
Thanks for your help, 
Tom

Comment: Exactly how is the original exercise worded? And, is $\Delta$ any group?

Comment: *a subrepresentation should look like $B\subseteq A$  in module language* I agree with that. In any case, $B$ would be a quotient representation of $A$...

Comment: A surjection means $B$ is a quotient of $A$.  Now $\Delta$ is prime to $p$, so representations are semisimple, so subrep and quotient rep is the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for your hint! Are submodules and quotient modules the same in the semi-simple case because every short exact sequence splits?

Comment: The $k[G]$ modules are semisimple, so all submodules are direct summands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tharris and Aaron pointed out, for a field $k$ (e.g. $\mathbb{F}_p$) whose characteristic does not divide the group order $|\Delta|$, Maschke's theorem asserts that any $k[\Delta]$-module is semisimple, which is per definition equivalent to the fact that every submodule is a direct summand. Hence any quotient module must be a submodule.

Thanks to you, guys!